# How to insert upper convected time derivative in latex?

Tags: latex

I am trying to learn how to write in Latex, but unfortunately I was not able to find a command to write an upper convected time derivative.
In particular, I am interested in writing a little triangle-down on the top of a letter, as shown in the picture.

[image: Upper-convected]

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

\[  
  \stackrel{\kern0.3em\smalltriangledown}{A}
\]
      
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, just another simple question: when I use the command \[..\]  the following equation is not enumerated, is there some way to do so?

Comment: if you have a new question, use the "ask question" button

Answer (score 0):

An alternative syntax to the other answer, giving similar output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
\[
\overset{\kern0.25em\smalltriangledown}{A}
\]
\end{document}
```

Package `amsmath` provides the command `\overset`, while package `MnSymbol` provides the command `\smalltriangledown`.